# DataFrame.apply(func, raw=True) doesn't seem to take effect?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to hash together only a few columns of my dataframe `df` so I do

```
temp = df['field1', 'field2']
df["hash"] = temp.apply(lambda x: hash(x), raw=True, axis=1)
```

I set raw to true because the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) (I am using 0.22) says it will pass a numpy array instead of a mutable Series but even with `raw=True` I am getting a Series, why?

```
  File "/nix/store/9ampki9dbq0imhhm7i27qkh56788cjpz-python3.6-pandas-0.22.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4877, in apply
    ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
  File "/nix/store/9ampki9dbq0imhhm7i27qkh56788cjpz-python3.6-pandas-0.22.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4973, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "/home/teto/mptcpanalyzer/mptcpanalyzer/data.py", line 190, in _hash_row
    return hash(x)
  File "/nix/store/9ampki9dbq0imhhm7i27qkh56788cjpz-python3.6-pandas-0.22.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1045, in __hash__
    ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", 'occurred at index 1')
```

Comment: What is function `hash` ? Can you create some sample data, 3-4 rows with sample function?

Comment: @jezrael presumably it is the [builtin `hash` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash).

Comment: yes I use the builtin it should be enough for my purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange, as I can't reproduce your exact error (that is, by me, `raw=True` indeed results in an `np.ndarray` being passed). In any case, neither a `Series` nor a `np.ndarray` are hashable. The following works, though:

```
temp.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
```

A `tuple` *is* hashable.

Comment: hmmm, convert to values is not necessary, `df['hash'] = temp.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis = 1)` working nice.

Comment: Thanks, @jezrael! Updated.

Comment: weird I was using `hash(tuple(x.tolist()))` but values look better. That's good enough for my purpose, especially as np.ndarray is mutable too. I am not sure why raw won't work here but if it works for you then maybe it was fixed or I did sthg wrong. Thanks for trying

Comment: Just for the record, what is your Pandas version, and what is the output of `temp.apply(type, axis=1, raw=True)`? My version is 0.24.2, and that command shows "Series" type.